# Unit Test fails after updating my code to pass view model to my views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Below I have a test method which successfully runs until now that I updated my code for respecting the view model pattern.

**Before**: I had an EditProject action method with an entity model as parameter. I had no problems with testing, see code below, point (d).

This was not a good idea to pass an entity model to my views. So I updated my code in order to pass only view models to my views (I use Automapper).

**After updating my controller code**: now, the EditProject action method works with a view model parameter. It works when running the website but my test method fails.

Below is my original test method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Save_Valid_Changes() 
{
    // (a) Arrange - create mock repository
    Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();

    // (b) Arrange - create the controller
    AdminController target = new AdminController(mock.Object);

    // (c) Arrange - create a product
    Product product = new Product {Name = "Test"};

    // (d) Act - try to save the product
    ActionResult result = target.Edit(product);

    // (e) Assert - check that the repository was called
    mock.Verify(m => m.SaveProduct(product));

    // (f) Assert - check the method result type
    Assert.IsNotInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
}
```

I don't know what I have to change in my test method. I try updating my test method and adding some mapping from model to viewModel but it fails (on the h2 line). Error: *Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: m => m.SaveProject(.model)
No setups configured.*

```
    public void Can_Save_Valid_Changes()
    {
        // (a2) Arrange - create mock repository
        Mock<IProjectRepository> mock = new Mock<IProjectRepository>();

        // (b2) Arrange - create the controller
        AdminController target = new AdminController(mock.Object);

        // (c2) Arrange - create a product
        Project project = new Project { ProjectID = 1, Name = "Test" };

        // (d2) Create the maps
        Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ProjectViewModel, Project>();  

        // (e2) Map model into view model
        ProjectViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<Project, ProjectViewModel>(project);

        // (f2) Act - try to save the product
        ActionResult result = target.EditProject(viewModel);

        // (g2) Map view model into model
        Project model = Mapper.Map<ProjectViewModel, Project>(viewModel);

        // (h2) Assert - check that the repository was called
        mock.Verify(m => m.SaveProject(model));

        // (i2) Assert - check the method result type
        Assert.IsNotInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this worked in the original example is because the product object that you acted on steps (d) and (e) was the same object and therefore the Save operation was detected.

However, in the refactored version you are acting on different objects. You create a viewModel (e2), pass it to the controller (f2), inside the controller you probably converted the viewModel to a model and save it but that model is **not** the one used in step h2 to evaluate whether a save was executed. Instead, in step h2 you are using a new model object created on g2 where the save operation has not been called.

Comment: You are right: this is the problem. Now, how can I update this code in order to unit test "Can_Save_Valid_Changes" ?

Comment: Personally I would start by making a separate unit test to test the save functionality. For example, a unit test that converts a viewModel to a Model, saves the model, and make sure the save was called (i.e. a unit test without any of the other stuff). I realize this does not directly address your problem but without knowing much about your project it's hard for me to suggest anything else.